# What is the time complexity of n * n * n iterations inside a for loop?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity of these loops? Correct me if I am wrong.

This loop is O(n^3) because it's got (n^3)/2 + 1 iterations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * n * n; i+=2)
{
     //body
}
```

and

This loop is O(n^3 * m^2) since it has (n^3 + 1) * (m^2 + 1) iterations. Or would this just be O(n^3) since the inner loop is not a variable n?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * n * n; i+=2)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < m * m; j++)
     {
     //Body
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you're correct, apart from instead of "since it has (n^3 + 1) * (m^2 + 1)" it should be, as you did for the first analysis, n^3/2...

Comment: Well it depends what `m` and `n` are. In the first case, if `n` is a constant then the loop is constant time O(1). Remember, free and bound variables... As you write it, we generally consider both n and m as free, then first is of O(n^3) and second of O(n^3*m^2) (outer loop occurs n^3 and for each of these inner loop occurs m^2).

Answer (score 4):

In the first case the time complexity is `O(n^3)`. It captures the most significant term so you ignore the scaling factor of `1/2` and the constant `+1`. In the latter case it is `O(n^3 * m^2)` unless you treat `m` as a constant and not as a variable. In the Big-O notation you don't necessary need to have only a single variable to represent the size of the input data.

Answer (score 2):

> This loop is O(n^3) because it's got (n^3)/2 + 1 iterations.

Correct.

> This loop is O(n^3 * m^2) since it has (n^3 + 1) * (m^2 + 1) iterations. Or would this just be O(n^3) since the inner loop is not a variable n?

Both are correct. It depends if you consider `m` a variable or a constant.

Answer (score 0):

In asymptotic notations one can have more than one variables.
For the second case considering both n and m as variables the complexity will be O(n^3 * m^2). If m is treated as a constant then the complexity is O(n^3).